# Customize Add Stock Item in SO and PO

Tags: acumatica

currently I am doing some customization in "add stock item" of Sales Order and Purchase Order in acumatica, in this customization I added "Marked For" column but it is not editable even though its already there, how can I make it editable for the users?

Attached here is the screenshot of customized "add stock item".

Things done:

- Extended SoSiteStatusSelected DAC.
- Edited .aspx and added Marked For Column[image: SO Marked For]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your field to your SOOrderStatusSelected DAC extension. It has to be an unbound field because the DAC is not bound to a table. You can add further logic in event handlers to persist to database.

```
public class SOSiteStatusSelectedExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOSiteStatusSelected>
{
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Marked For")]
    public virtual string UsrMarkedFor { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrMarkedFor : IBqlField { }
}
```

Enable the field in SOOrderEntry graph extension in the RowSelected event:

```
public class SOOrderEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
     protected virtual void SOSiteStatusSelected_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
     {
          PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<PX.Objects.SO.SOSiteStatusSelectedExt.usrMarkedFor>(sender, e.Row, true);
     }
```

Tested in Acumatica v6.10.0010 for SalesOrder screen:

[image]

Comment: I am getting an error "Object must be type of string", that is after I make marked for a selector from Marked For screen. I tried to change the datatype to string but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Digging into SOSiteStatusLookup which is inherited from INSiteStatusLookup you will find that 'OnRowSelected' it is disabling all fields except for 'Selected' and 'QtySelected' columns. To override this, try adding the following to a SOOrderEntry graph extension for any field you want to add to this view as editable from your extension...

```
protected virtual void SOSiteStatusSelected_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
{
    del?.Invoke(sender, e);         

    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<MyExtension.MyField>(sender, e.Row, true);
}
```

Replace 'MyExtension' with your class extension name and 'MyField' with the mark for field name.